# Celery Python - Run A Chord Callback Only After All Tasks In Body Have Finished All Retries Or Succeeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I'm currently using celery with rabbitMQ to handle decentralization of message queues.
I'm facing a bit of an issue, where sometimes the network im on may fall for an hour or so.
I want to be able to create a vast dependency tree of chords, and send it and let it run in the backround. This means chord inside a chord inside a chord...
Now, some of my tasks have retires, lets say once every 30 mins, 3 times max.
I want the chord who's currently running to wait for the all the tasks in the group to finish their max retries or until they are all successful, failing only if some failed after all the retries.
Currently while running my chord, I retry tasks and after they succeed my chord doesn't execute the callback.

Celery == 5.2.7

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks a lot!

I tried making a task that fails twice and only succeeds after the third retry, made a group of them, and put it in a chord with one final task that indicates success as a callback.
I expected the chord callback to proc after all tasks in the groups work, instead it didnt, even after the tasks in the group retried twice and succeeded.